# Stream manipulating indenter

Tags: c++, formatting, stream

I've always wanted to be able to steer stream indentation, so that I could write code like this:

```
/// This probably has to be called once for every program:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387054/how-can-i-use-stdimbue-to-set-the-locale-for-stdwcout
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::cout << "I want to push indentation levels:\n" << indent_manip::push
          << "To arbitrary depths\n" << indent_manip::push
          << "and pop them\n" << indent_manip::pop
          << "back down\n" << indent_manip::pop
          << "like this.\n"
```

Finally, I've done it, but I had to do a kind of nasty hack.

The problem is:

1. I need to call a facet that is called on every string, which appears to mean that I have to use codecvt.
2. I need the indentation level  to persist, which means using `iosbase::iword`.
3. `codecvt` doesn't have a reference to `iosbase` anywhere.

Combine all that with the fact that facets have to be constant objects, and you get a kind of tricky problem.  I solved it with a dirty trick:

- I use `iword` to keep track of the indentation level, since I get stream tracking for free that way.  If I was only dealing with a single stream it would useless information.
- Whenever `indent_manip::push` is called, the `iword` is incremented, a new fact is created, a locale is created with that facet, and the current stream is imbued with that locale.

I put the implementation, along with a more involved demo/test on [GitHub](https://github.com/spacemoose/ostream_indenter).

Tested on gcc 5.1 with:

```
g++ -o indenter  --std=c++14 indent_test.cpp
```

**What I'm most interested in**

Obviously it's not going to win performance prizes, and there's some easy places to optimize.  I'm curious about the safety of what I'm trying to do.  Is there a cleaner alternative?

Obviously I can create a custom `ostream`, and that'll be phase two, but I have a use case where I want to imbue this behavior into an existing `std::ostream`, and this was the only way I could figure out how to do it.

How's the usability?

```
#pragma once

#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>



class indent_facet : public std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t> {
public:
    explicit indent_facet( int indent_level, size_t ref = 0)
        : std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t>(ref), m_indentation_level(indent_level) {}
    typedef std::codecvt_base::result result;
    typedef std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t> parent;
    typedef parent::intern_type intern_type;
    typedef parent::extern_type extern_type;
    typedef parent::state_type  state_type;

    int &state(state_type &s) const { return *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&s); }

protected:
    virtual result do_out(state_type &need_indentation,
        const intern_type *from, const intern_type *from_end, const intern_type *&from_next,
        extern_type *to, extern_type *to_end, extern_type *&to_next
        ) const override;

    // Override so the do_out() virtual function is called.
    virtual bool do_always_noconv() const throw() override {
        return m_indentation_level==0;
    }
    unsigned int m_indentation_level = 0;

};

indent_facet::result indent_facet::do_out(state_type &need_indentation,
    const intern_type *from, const intern_type *from_end, const intern_type *&from_next,
    extern_type *to, extern_type *to_end, extern_type *&to_next
    ) const
{
    result res = std::codecvt_base::noconv;
    for (; (from < from_end) && (to < to_end); ++from, ++to) {
        // 0 indicates that the last character seen was a newline.
        // thus we will print a tab before it. Ignore it the next
        // character is also a newline
        if ((state(need_indentation) == 0) && (*from != '\n')) {
            res = std::codecvt_base::ok;
            state(need_indentation) = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<m_indentation_level; ++i){
                *to = '\t'; ++to;
            }
            if (to == to_end) {
                res = std::codecvt_base::partial;
                break;
            }
        }
        *to = *from; // Copy the next character.

        // If the character copied was a '\n' mark that state
        if (*from == '\n') {
            state(need_indentation) = 0;
        }
    }

    if (from != from_end) {
        res = std::codecvt_base::partial;
    }
    from_next = from;
    to_next = to;

    return res;
};



/// I hate the way I solved this, but I can't think of a better way
/// around the problem.  I even asked stackoverflow for help:
///
///   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480237/apply-a-facet-to-all-stream-output-use-custom-string-manipulators
///
///
namespace  indent_manip{

static const int index = std::ios_base::xalloc();

static std::ostream & push(std::ostream& os)
{
    auto ilevel = ++os.iword(index);
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), new indent_facet(ilevel)));
    return os;
}

std::ostream& pop(std::ostream& os)
{
    auto ilevel = (os.iword(index)>0) ? --os.iword(index) : 0;
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), new indent_facet(ilevel)));
    return os;
}

/// Clears the ostream indentation set, but NOT the raii_guard.
std::ostream& clear(std::ostream& os)
{
    os.iword(index) = 0;
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), new indent_facet(0)));
    return os;
}



/// Provides a RAII guard around your manipulation.
class raii_guard
{
public:
    raii_guard(std::ostream& os):
        start_level(os.iword(index)),
        oref(os)
    {}

    ~raii_guard()
    {
        reset();
    }

    /// Resets the streams indentation level to the point itw as at
    /// when the guard was created.
    void reset()
    {
        oref.iword(index) = start_level;
        oref.imbue(std::locale(oref.getloc(), new indent_facet(start_level)));
    }

private:
    std::ostream& oref;
     int start_level;
};

}
```

Comment: Don't think too much about a custom ostream. I think it's **a lot more useful** if you can imbue it on any `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: this answer is really more of an SO-style answer about the right way to solve this problem than it is a review of this code. I apologize for that, but I do hope you'll forgive me, and perhaps even read on to see why.

Neither a facet nor a custom ostream is the right way to solve this problem. Your question on SO (which I'm sorry I missed when it was posted) is (at least in my opinion) nearly a perfect example of the XY problem. You asked something very specific about facets, but the reality is that a facet just isn't the right tool for the job.

So, having said nasty things (sorry 'bout that) about the approach you've taken, what would I do instead? I'd recommend a custom streambuf. It's basically a complete rewrite from the ground up, so I'm not going to spend a lot of effort on reviewing your code as it stands right now. Instead, I'll try to point you in a direction I think is better, with a bit of code I wrote some time ago. It's not *quite* exactly what you're trying to do, but it's similar, and does show a better way to integrate the basic capability into iostreams.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iomanip>

class widthbuf: public std::streambuf {
public:
    widthbuf(int w, std::streambuf* s)
        : indent_width(0), 
        def_width(w), 
        width(w), 
        sbuf(s), 
        count(0) 
    {}

    ~widthbuf() { overflow('\n'); }

    void set_indent(int w) { 
        if (w == 0) {
            prefix.clear();
            indent_width = 0;
            width = def_width;
        }
        else {
            indent_width += w; 
            prefix = string(indent_width, space);
            width -= w; 
        }
    }

private:

    typedef std::basic_string<char_type> string;

    // This is basically a line-buffering stream buffer.
    // The algorithm is: 
    // - Explicit end of line ("\r" or "\n"): we flush our buffer 
    //   to the underlying stream's buffer, and set our record of
    //   the line length to 0.
    // - An "alert" character: sent to the underlying stream
    //   without recording its length, since it doesn't normally
    //   affect the a appearance of the output.
    // - tab: treated as occupying `tab_width` characters, but is 
    //   passed through undisturbed (but if we wanted to expand it
    //   to `tab_width` spaces, that would be pretty easy to do so
    //   you could adjust the tab-width if you wanted.
    // - Everything else: really basic buffering with word wrapping. 
    //   We try to add the character to the buffer, and if it exceeds
    //   our line width, we search for the last space/tab in the 
    //   buffer and break the line there. If there is no space/tab, 
    //   we break the line at the limit.
    int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        if (traits_type::eq_int_type(traits_type::eof(), c))
            return traits_type::not_eof(c);
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
        case '\r': 
            {
                buffer += c;
                count = 0;
                sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                int_type rc = sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
                buffer.clear();
                return rc;
            }
        case '\a':
            return sbuf->sputc(c);
        case '\t':
            buffer += c;
            count += tab_width - count % tab_width;
            return c;
        default:
            if (count >= width) {
                size_t wpos = buffer.find_last_of(" \t");
                if (wpos != string::npos) {
                    sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                    sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), wpos);
                    count = buffer.size()-wpos-1;
                    buffer = string(buffer, wpos+1);
                }
                else {
                    sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                    sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
                    buffer.clear();
                    count = 0;
                }
                sbuf->sputc('\n');
            }
            buffer += c;
            ++count;
            return c;
        }
    }

    size_t indent_width;
    size_t width, def_width;
    size_t count;
    size_t tab_count;
    static const int tab_width = 8;
    string prefix;

    char_type space = static_cast<char_type>(' ');

    std::streambuf* sbuf;

    string buffer;
};

class widthstream : public std::ostream {
    widthbuf buf;
public:
    widthstream(size_t width, std::ostream &os) 
        : buf(width, os.rdbuf()), 
        std::ostream(&buf) 
    {}

    widthstream &indent(int w) { 
        buf.set_indent(w); 
        return *this; 
    }
};

int main() {
    widthstream out(30, std::cout);
    out.indent(10) << "This is a very long string that will wrap to the"
        " next line because it is a very long string that will wrap to "
        "the next line.\n";
    out.indent(0) << "This is\tsome\tmore text that should not be indented "
        "but should still be word wrapped to 30 columns.";
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's an XY problem... as I say towards the end of my post: "Obviously I can create a custom ostream, and that'll be phase two, but I have a use case where I want to imbue this behavior into an existing std::ostream, and this was the only way I could figure out how to do it.".  The idea is to be able to indent existing output in code I don't want to/can't modify.

Comment: @Spacemoose: Yes, this supports attaching the streambuf to an existing stream (the `widthstream` class is convenient, but not really needed). Although I had this code handy, I should add that for what you want (just indenting) the code can actually be a *lot* simpler as well.